# asp.net4.5 ckfinder2.5.0 uploader file failed

Tags: asp.net, ckfinder

ENV: asp.net4.5 with ckfinder2.5.0(dll),and upload picture in ckeditor4.5.3_full.
setps:

1. config this as normal  ckeditor and ckfinder configuration.
2. Browser picture.
3. click send to server, then an error message pops up with "upload files damaged"
4. I do this in asp.net4.0 without this error.

Does anyone know what going on with this?

Comment: CKFinder's "the uploaded file is corrupt" for ASP.Net 4.5

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/The-solution-of-CKFinders-the-uploaded-file-is-corrupt-for-ASP.Net-4.5

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem resolved this morning, there i would like appreciate  http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/The-solution-of-CKFinders-the-uploaded-file-is-corrupt-for-ASP.Net-4.5

solution:
1. find App_Start/RouteConfig.cs in my .net 4.5 webapplication solution.
2. override ConvertToFriendlyUrl() method as below code:

```
public class MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver : WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver
{
    public override string ConvertToFriendlyUrl(string path)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            if (path.ToLower().Contains("/resource/ckfinder"))
            {
                return path;
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path) ;
    }
}
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        //routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings, new Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers.IFriendlyUrlResolver[] { new MyWebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver() }); 
    }
}
```

3. upload again, it works.

Comment: Make sure to import Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers in order to pick up WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver.